# How to update selected sharepoint list items with javascript,

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, updates

Hi this works fine on button click ; it loops selected items in the view, alerts the id & calls the updateListItem function

```
function ViewSelectedItems(){
var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) { alert("Item with Id = " + selectedItems[i].id+ " is selected");  updateListItem(selectedItems[i].id)}
                 window.location.href = window.location.href;
}
```

the updateListItem reports onQuerySucceeded but the field value is not set to the new value. Any ideas please?

```
    function updateListItem(passedid) {

 var siteUrl = '/supportdepts/hr/';

 var newval = 999;

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Staffing Control Panel Request');
    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(passedid);
    oListItem.set_item("RefNumber", newval);
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 


    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not so very familiar with the case but I do know that when this kind of trouble occur even though the code seems OK, the values which should navigate the code are probably mistaken. In other words, maybe the list name you are using is not the real name but the display name. You should make sure the names you are using are the real schema's names of the lists and fields and not just the display ones.

I hope I did help somehow. G o o d   L u c k!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to refresh the browser?

The same code worked for me, but i need to refresh browser to view item's new values.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same issue and it's due to the fact that the page refresh occurs before the async event is done, which means the context is lost. So that the item is not saved, even though everything seems perfect before calling `executeQueryAsync`.
If you remove the refresh, it should work.